# WPF datagrid with checkListBox drop down

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, ultrawingrid

I am fairly new to WPF development . I would like to create a WPF datagrid with the following columns : CheckBox column ,Text column , button column , checklist box drop down column and combobox drop down column. I also need to add listeners to the checklist box drop down columns . I have created the same in winforms using Infragistics Ultragrid . It looks like this :

I read up on adding some custom control to datagrid in wpf using DataGridTemplateColumn but am not sure how to implement this. Can Template take in Combobox and Checklistbox ? A short code example would be great. Will I have to use infragistics or can this UI be realised using WPF standard controls?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with standard WPF controls. That's one of the greatest parts about WPF - it is extremely flexible (usually without too much effort). Here is an example that should get you pointed in the right direction:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Selected"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="Click Me!" 
                                        Command="{Binding myItemCommand}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Task" 
                                        Binding="{Binding TaskText}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Resources" 
                                        Binding="{Binding ResourcesText}"/>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableStatuses}" 
                                            SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedStatus}" 
                                            Header="Status" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Resources}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsResourceUsed}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ResourceName}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Once you get inside of the  tag as shown above, you can put pretty much whatever controls inside of it that you want and they will be repeated for each row. The binding for each item is tied to whatever object the row represents, so if you have a list of task objects that your DataGrid is displaying, each task in that list should have properties to bind to for the TaskText, ResourcesText, etc.

EDIT: Updated the code snippet to show a RowDetailsTemplate. If a RowDetailsTemplate with something like another DataGrid inside of it doesn't get the job done, you could always write your own multi-select combobox, but it might be fairly involved, as the default one has no good way that I know of to allow you to select multiple items.

Comment: It looks like OP want a MV combobox for resources.  But that can be solved and plugged into DataGridTemplateColumn.   Pras you should ask about MV combobox in a separate question.

Comment: Taylor : Thanks for the answer . That lets me get started but the Resources column is not text . It has to be a drop down with checkboxes.
Blam : you are right . Though am not sure MV combobox will have that check list box UI set up. It will most likely be a combobox with multi select option. anyway i can add a checklistbox to the Resources column ?

Comment: drats! there's no checkListBox control in WPF :'(

Comment: Sorry, I missed the checkListBox part. A couple of thoughts: you could use a RowDetailsTemplate and put an ItemsControl inside of it so that when you click on the row, you see list of all resources with checkboxes next to them. You could still parse all of those into a string to display in a ResourcesString column in your ViewModel. Another thought is some sort of custom control in the TemplateColumn that pops out and gives you the options you need, but that would be a lot more work to get looking right.

Comment: okay. thank you very much Taylor. will you be able to provide a short code sample on the Row details method ? at the cost of being close to spoon feeding.

Comment: Edited the original post with a RowDetailsTemplate. You can stick anything you want into the RowDetails template and it will show you more information for the selected row. The example I provided would be bound to a collection of Resource objects and then each row in the details template would be one of the available resources with a checkbox next to it. More details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailstemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx